# Replace Add to Cart Button URL with a specific URL along with button lable on Single Product Page upon previous completed order

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

there I am trying to change the Label of Add to Cart Button to 'View Lecture' if the customer had already purchased the product and the URL to a specific one. Below is my code snippet, it is working fine on shop page but is not working on Single Product page.

**Anyone please suggest the required changes in the code so that it shall work on Single Product page too.**

```
// function to check if a customer has bought a product (Order with "completed" status only)

   add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link','add_to_cart_link_customer_has_bought');

    function add_to_cart_link_customer_has_bought() {

        global $product;

        if( empty( $product->id ) ){

            $wc_pf = new WC_Product_Factory();
            $product = $wc_pf->get_product( $id );

        }

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        if( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->id ) ){

            $product_url = "https://editorials.in/package/onlinecoaching/";
            $button_label =  "View Lecture";  

        } else {

            $product_url =  $product->add_to_cart_url();  
            $button_label = $product->add_to_cart_text();

        };

        echo sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product_url ),
            esc_attr( $product->id ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
            $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
            esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
            esc_html( $button_label )
        );

    }
```

Comment: In action name `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` you can see it state word `loop` so this action is only for the product loop, as you also want to change the url and text for a single page, then you'll have to modify *add to cart* templates. check the folder `templates/single-product/add-to-cart` you'll find files based on default woocommerce product types. you'll have to customize those files in your child theme.

Comment: I want the change dynamically using conditional checking, Will this work in dynamic way?